# ignoring file, missing required architecture x86_64 in file .../Social.framework/Social (3 Slices)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have read lot of questions on SO and got no where so decided to post this. I removed Twitter.framework because it was red and I already had Social.framwork so I got errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Then I checked there was an error message

```
 ignoring file /Users/saheelsehgal/Downloads/Social.framework/Social, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/saheelsehgal/Downloads/Social.framework/Social (3 slices)
```

Any help? I am getting very frustrated and I have already followed there SO answers and re-installed Xcode 6.3.2 and also messed around with architecture.
[image]

Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `Social` framework you downloaded
2. Link against `Accounts` and `Social` frameworks that are shipped with Xcode (press the `+` button under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` in your target `General` settings)
3. Build and profit !
   [image]

Comment: Sorry, But didn't work! Still same error! I was trying to add Social.framework that came with Xcode but when I searched, it wasn't there. So i re-installed Xcode and i could see it. But it doesn't make any difference.